# Entity Framework query to extract total count while using ToPageList

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm fetching some db results using the ToPagedList() plugin for paging. My query fetches the first 6 results per 'Page' which is ok, but I would like to know if there is a way I can write the query to return me the total count of results with the same query so I don't have to run 2 different db queries.

Here is my query

```
using (var dbContext = new YogabandyContext())
        {
            viewModel.Events = (from u in dbContext.YogaSpaceEvents
            where
                (u.EventDateTime >= Date) &&
                (u.LocationPoints.Distance(location) <= radius)
            select new EventResult
            {
                SpaceId = u.YogaSpaceRefId,
                Title = u.Title,
                // set more values here

            }).OrderBy(d => d.Date).ToPagedList(Page, 6);
            // && return total count of all events in addition to the 6 for that page
        }
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the extension, but if I'm looking at the right github I see that the extension apparently returns an IPagedList interface that enforces a TotalItemCount property, as well as a PageCount and PageSize that could be used to calculate.

https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList

Comment: This has been asked before and you shouldn't want this. It means that you have to write a LINQ query repeating itself in one statement. This yields a complex query that's not likely to perform any better than a separate count query.